# Flash, actionscript...load and parseXML with scrolling

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript, stylesheet, scroller

I would like to add a component in my flash website which will,
  1.load xml data.
  2.parse it using stylesheet
  3. Have a scrollbar incase xml data is a lot.

any suggestions will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Load your XML file with URLLoader.
2. Use the listener Event.COMPLETE and
   cast the data to XML.
3. Parse through the children of the XML
   through a loop or recursively and
   build data objects.
4. Render the
   data objects into a TextField with
   span tags and apply a stylesheet
   according to the formatting you require.

Of course there are other ways but I'm making guesses at what you're looking to use this application for.

Answer (score 0):

following on Henry's answer...

create a sprite container to hold your textfields. set a maximum display height , when the container's height exceeds the max display height , add a scrollbar.